# How to rewrite my URL so that it works well with $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx

I have an application with a single point of entry. In that application, I have the following line:

```
$url = !empty($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]) ? $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] : "/";
```

This allows me to process URLs when I access them like so:

```
http://localhost/index.php/controller/action?get=variables
```

All is well, but the OCD I am, I want to get rid of the `index.php` part of the URL. And no matter what I've tried, it didn't work as expected.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
#or
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

etc.

Some of them produce a loop error in my nginx error log (too many rewrites), some of them just don't work at all.

I'm at a standstill here. How can I successfully rewrite such a URL? **Note that I'm using Nginx and *not* Apache)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative lookahead.

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try and get back to you.